# Jquery .change function only responses to one of the radiolists options

Tags: jquery

I have radiobuttonlist which I want make some divs visible/invisible with. Here is my radiobuttonlist:

```
echo $form->radioButtonList($model, 'klant',
                    array(  '1' => 'Ja',
                            '0' => 'Nee' ));
```

The Jquery that calls the .onchange:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#Nieuwsbrief_klant_1').change(function () {
        alert($(this).val());
    });
});
```

Now I only get an alert is I click 'nee'. When I click 'ja' nothing happens. Why does it only fire with one options? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using the id selector `$('#Nieuwsbrief_klant_1')` so it applies the event only to one element. You should have only one element per id anyway, you might want to use a class selector or something else more generic.

Comment: So, complete logic that one element worked and the other didn't :p. Thanks!